# SQL Date Range Split

Tags: sql, date-range

Can you please let me know the SQL to split date ranges when they overlap?

Data (sample data with a date range and possibly other columns):

```
    Col1 FromDate ToDate
 1. 1    1/1/2008 31/12/2010
 2. 1    1/1/2009 31/12/2012
 3. 1    1/1/2009 31/12/2014
```

Output:

```
   Col1  From Date ToDate
1. 1     1/1/2008 31/12/2008 (from row 1 above)
2. 1     1/1/2009 31/12/2010 (from rows 1,2 and 3 above)
3. 1     1/1/2011 31/12/2012 (from rows 2 and 3 above)
4. 1     1/1/2013 31/12/2014 (from row 3 above)
```

Comment: Ok, I don't have the complete answer, but here are some points to consider. 1. The first block of time is select min(FromDate) from table group by FromDate`print("code sample");` 2. Then end of the first block is select min(FromDate) from table group by FromDate where FromDate > "start of block" 3. Repeat as needed. :)

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick (MySQL dialect, but easily adaptable)

Initial setup

```
SQL query: SELECT * FROM `test` LIMIT 0, 30 ;
Rows: 3
start       end
2008-01-01  2010-12-31
2009-01-01  2012-12-31
2009-01-01  2014-12-31
```

Query

```
SELECT 
  `start` , min( `end` )
FROM (
  SELECT t1.start, t2.end
  FROM test t1, test t2
  WHERE t1.start < t2.end
  UNION
  SELECT t1.end + INTERVAL 1 DAY , t2.end
  FROM test t1, test t2
  WHERE t1.end + INTERVAL 1 DAY < t2.end
  UNION
  SELECT t1.start, t2.start - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  FROM test t1, test t2
  WHERE t1.start < t2.start - INTERVAL 1 DAY
) allRanges
GROUP BY `start`
```

Result

```
start       min( `end` )
2008-01-01  2008-12-31
2009-01-01  2010-12-31
2011-01-01  2012-12-31
2013-01-01  2014-12-31
```

Answer (score 2):

Skliwz's answer adapted for SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @DateTest TABLE 
(
    FromDate datetime,
    ToDate datetime 
)

insert into @DateTest (FromDate, ToDate)
(
select cast('1/1/2008' as datetime), cast('12/31/2010' as datetime)
union
select cast('1/1/2009' as datetime), cast('12/31/2012' as datetime)
union
select cast('1/1/2009' as datetime), cast('12/31/2014' as datetime)
)

SELECT 
  FromDate , min(ToDate)
FROM (
  SELECT t1.FromDate, t2.ToDate
  FROM 
    @DateTest t1, 
    @DateTest t2
  WHERE t1.FromDate < t2.ToDate

  UNION

  SELECT dateadd(DAY, 1, t1.ToDate), t2.ToDate
  FROM 
    @DateTest t1, 
    @DateTest t2
  WHERE dateadd(DAY, 1, t1.ToDate) < t2.ToDate
) allRanges
group by FromDate
```