# How to get activity status that occurred within a interval during start and stop datetime(SQL)(t-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to have a query for below scenario.
I have a table with event and occurence time as below:

```
EventName     OccuredAtDatetime
EventA        2019-07-03 00:14:01
EventA        2019-07-03 01:14:01
EventA        2019-07-03 01:34:01
EventB        2019-07-03 01:13:03
```

I would like to know whether a event has occured within a time interval (30 minutes in this example) , say starttime as 2019-07-03 00:00:00 and endtime as 2019-07-03 02:00:00, the interval would be like

```
IntervalName     StartTime                EndTime
Interval1       2019-07-03 00:00:00       2019-07-03 00:30:00
Interval2       2019-07-03 00:30:00       2019-07-03 01:00:00
Interval3       2019-07-03 01:00:00       2019-07-03 01:30:00
Interval4       2019-07-03 01:30:00       2019-07-03 02:00:00
```

So, the output would be like,

```
EventName     Interval1    Interval2       Interval3        Interval4
EventA        Yes          No              Yes              Yes
EventB        No           No              Yes              No
```

This is also my first post on stackoverflow so please let me know if the data are not in the preferred format or if there any additional questions. Thanks!

Comment: First you need table of numbers see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58023016/split-date-range-from-a-single-row-into-months-that-are-displayed-in-multiple-ro for example. Next you need dynamic pivot (a lot of answers here) as the number of output columns is varying.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your tables are called Events and Intervals, this will do:

```
with cte as (
select e.EventName,
    i.IntervalName
from Events as e
    cross apply Intervals as i 
where e.OccuredAtDatetime>= i.StartTime
  and e.OccuredAtDatetime < i.EndTime
)
select  e.EventName,
        max(IIF(c.IntervalName='Interval1','Yes','No')) as Interval1,
        max(IIF(c.IntervalName='Interval2','Yes','No')) as Interval2,
        max(IIF(c.IntervalName='Interval3','Yes','No')) as Interval3,
        max(IIF(c.IntervalName='Interval4','Yes','No')) as Interval4
from events as e
    left outer join cte as c ON e.EventName = c.EventName
group by e.EventName
```

Basically the cte is finding all the instances that occurred, and the second select is just for formatting according to what you asked for.

Comment: Actually, all I have is Events table. "Interval" table is supposed to be auto-created based on the interval (15minute,30minute,1 hour,etc) . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by executing a dynamic SQL query.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);
select @sql = 'select [t1].[EventName], ' + stuff((
        select ', max(case when [IntervalName] = ' + char(39) + [IntervalName] + char(39)
        + ' and [t1].OccuredAtDatetime between [t2].[StartTime] and [t2].[EndTime] then '
        + char(39) + 'Yes' + char(39) + ' else ' + char(39) + 'No' + char(39) 
        + ' end) as [' + [IntervalName] + ']'
        from [intervals]
        for xml path('')
    ),
    1, 1, ''
)
+ ' from [events] as [t1], [intervals] as [t2]'
+ ' group by [t1].[EventName];';

exec(@sql);
```

**[Find demo here](https://rextester.com/TPRX23331)**

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Output has dynamic columns now. G8